# ProfiledDbConnection.cs not found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, umbraco

I'm trying to install Umbraco in a new, empty Visual Studio Express 2013 project.

The installation seems to go OK and the project builds OK but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
ProfiledDbConnection.cs not found
```

I've found a couple of references to this error message on SO but none of them seem to relate to fresh installs and I am unclear as to how to progress.

Can anyone shed any light on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never invested the time to get to the bottom of this but you can skip over it or stop your debugger and reattach it when the site has loaded. It doesn't stop the site running and I think it is an exception thrown in a dependency somewhere which is handled before it bubbles up to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

click on customised button and selected SQL Server

Comment: click on customised button and selected SQL Server